# How do you find Image Rejection Ratio from doing FFT on ADC samples?

Tags: communication, wireless, signal-processing, sampling, fft

I'm trying to understand a particular code written by a former employee for measuring performance of an RX chain in a transceiver. I have to measure IRR(Image Rejection Ratio).

Certain input RF frequency is down converted to a baseband frequency of 76.8MHz. The output is sampled using ADC. I have 512 samples and sampling rate is 983.04 MHz.

My previous employee code **roughly** says

```
int Signal_Index= fft.maxPowerIndex();`  //**I understand this line**--
```

In the above line the max power for signal is at bin #40 which makes sense because 40*Fs/512=76.8MHz.

And then for image he writes the below line

```
int Image_Index=fft.size()-Signal_Index;` // **I don't understand this.**
```

After that he proceeds to calculate difference between power levels at both the signal and image bins and hence IRR

But I don't understand why image is at a different bin when in fact both image and signal are both down converted to same frequency.

Please note

1. LO freq and input RF freq are both greater than 30GHz
2. I understand what an Image is- that both signal and image are equal distance from LO freq. The relation being ω_im = ω_in + 2ω_IF

**Have I read the code wrongly?**